# How to restart NWListener once it was cancelled?

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming

I would like to receive some data via UDP in an endless loop until the user cancels the data receiving. I created an **NWListener**, and set it up. It receives data as expected. However once I call **.cancel()** on my **NWListener** it changes the state to **.cancelled** but afterwards I have no chance to restart the listening process again. It blocks somehow the port. I would be able to restart it on another port, but this is not what I want to do. On the same port it ends up in this error message:

```
2020-02-20 23:00:28.957501+0100 networking[10942:7110395] [] nw_path_evaluator_evaluate NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_ADD error [48: Address already in use]
2020-02-20 23:00:28.957642+0100 networking[10942:7110395] [] nw_path_create_evaluator_for_listener nw_path_evaluator_evaluate failed
2020-02-20 23:00:28.957735+0100 networking[10942:7110395] [] nw_listener_start_locked [L2] nw_path_create_evaluator_for_listener failed
 NWListener Handler called
Listener: Failed POSIXErrorCode: Address already in use
```

I created a dedicated sample project in Xcode to nail the issue down as good as possible and to ensure it has nothing to do with the rest of my actual project. This is the ViewController I created to show the problem, I just connected two buttons to start/stop UDP listening:

```
import UIKit
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var udpListener:NWListener?
    var backgroundQueueUdpListener   = DispatchQueue(label: "udp-lis.bg.queue", attributes: [])
    var backgroundQueueUdpConnection = DispatchQueue(label: "udp-con.bg.queue", attributes: [])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myOnButton(self)
    }

    @IBAction func myOnButton(_ sender: Any) {

        do {
            self.udpListener = try NWListener(using: .udp, on: 55555)
            self.udpListener?.stateUpdateHandler = { (listenerState) in
                print(" NWListener Handler called")
                switch listenerState {
                case .setup:
                    print("Listener: Setup")
                case .waiting(let error):
                    print("Listener: Waiting \(error)")
                case .ready:
                    print("Listener: ✅ Ready and listens on port: \(self.udpListener?.port?.debugDescription ?? "-")")
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("Listener: Failed \(error)")
                case .cancelled:
                    print("Listener:  Cancelled by myOffButton")
                default:
                    break;

                }
            }

            self.udpListener?.start(queue: backgroundQueueUdpListener)
            self.udpListener?.newConnectionHandler = { (incomingUdpConnection) in
                print(" NWConnection Handler called ")
                incomingUdpConnection.stateUpdateHandler = { (udpConnectionState) in

                    switch udpConnectionState {
                    case .setup:
                        print("Connection: ‍ setup")
                    case .waiting(let error):
                        print("Connection: ⏰ waiting: \(error)")
                    case .ready:
                        print("Connection: ✅ ready")
                        self.processData(incomingUdpConnection)
                    case .failed(let error):
                        print("Connection:  failed: \(error)")
                    case .cancelled:
                        print("Connection:  cancelled")
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }

                incomingUdpConnection.start(queue: self.backgroundQueueUdpConnection)
            }

        } catch {
            print(" CATCH")
        }

    }
    @IBAction func myOffButton(_ sender: Any) {
        udpListener?.cancel()
    }

    func processData(_ incomingUdpConnection :NWConnection) {

        incomingUdpConnection.receiveMessage(completion: {(data, context, isComplete, error) in

            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii) {
                    print ("DATA       = \(string)")
                }
            }
            //print ("context    = \(context)")
            print ("isComplete = \(isComplete)")
            //print ("error      = \(error)")

            self.processData(incomingUdpConnection)
        })

    }

}
```

I hope someone can help me, I spent now several hours to solve this issue, but without any success so far.

To test incoming messages via UDP, I used this shell script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
while :
do
    echo "1234" | nc -cu -w 0 192.168.2.106 55555
    sleep 1
    echo "567890" | nc -cu -w 0 192.168.2.106 55555
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I tested your code and had no error.

Comment: I tried now on two different Macs, and I found out it seems to work in simulator, but it does not work on real devices. What I noticed also is I can start and stop on real device as often as I like, but when I try to either start listening twice in a row,, or receive at least one message it gives the error. (Also only on real devices, in simulator it works as expected)

Comment: You can't start listening twice in a row (without an intervening stop). That is why I added the `guard` to the doe in my answer.

Comment: I do not want to start it twice, I just noticed by this that for some reason it looks like NWListener does not release the port when it received packages and going to .cancel afterwards. That's why there is difference in behavior of trying to start it twice or doing an intervening stop (.cancel) in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clean up all of the resources correctly; You need to keep track of your `NWConnection`s and make sure you cancel any when you cancel your listener, otherwise the socket isn't available for reuse.

I added an array to track the connections and ensure that all connections are cancelled when the lister is stopped.

To avoid infinite loops it also also important that you don't call `processData` when there is an error on the connection.

```
var udpListener:NWListener?
var backgroundQueueUdpListener   = DispatchQueue(label: "udp-lis.bg.queue", attributes: [])
var backgroundQueueUdpConnection = DispatchQueue(label: "udp-con.bg.queue", attributes: [])

var connections = [NWConnection]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myOnButton(self)
}

@IBAction func myOnButton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard self.udpListener == nil else {
        print("Already listening. Not starting again")
        return
    }

    do {
        self.udpListener = try NWListener(using: .udp, on: 55555)
        self.udpListener?.stateUpdateHandler = { (listenerState) in
            print(" NWListener Handler called")
            switch listenerState {
            case .setup:
                print("Listener: Setup")
            case .waiting(let error):
                print("Listener: Waiting \(error)")
            case .ready:
                print("Listener: ✅ Ready and listens on port: \(self.udpListener?.port?.debugDescription ?? "-")")
            case .failed(let error):
                print("Listener: Failed \(error)")
                self.udpListener = nil
            case .cancelled:
                print("Listener:  Cancelled by myOffButton")
                for connection in self.connections {
                    connection.cancel()
                }
                self.udpListener = nil
            default:
                break;

            }
        }

        self.udpListener?.start(queue: backgroundQueueUdpListener)
        self.udpListener?.newConnectionHandler = { (incomingUdpConnection) in
            print(" NWConnection Handler called ")
            incomingUdpConnection.stateUpdateHandler = { (udpConnectionState) in

                switch udpConnectionState {
                case .setup:
                    print("Connection: ‍ setup")
                case .waiting(let error):
                    print("Connection: ⏰ waiting: \(error)")
                case .ready:
                    print("Connection: ✅ ready")
                    self.connections.append(incomingUdpConnection)
                    self.processData(incomingUdpConnection)
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("Connection:  failed: \(error)")
                    self.connections.removeAll(where: {incomingUdpConnection === $0})
                case .cancelled:
                    print("Connection:  cancelled")
                    self.connections.removeAll(where: {incomingUdpConnection === $0})
                default:
                    break
                }
            }

            incomingUdpConnection.start(queue: self.backgroundQueueUdpConnection)
        }

    } catch {
        print(" CATCH")
    }

}
@IBAction func myOffButton(_ sender: Any) {
    udpListener?.cancel()
}

func processData(_ incomingUdpConnection :NWConnection) {

    incomingUdpConnection.receiveMessage(completion: {(data, context, isComplete, error) in

        if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
            if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii) {
                print ("DATA       = \(string)")
            }
        }
        //print ("context    = \(context)")
        print ("isComplete = \(isComplete)")
        if error == nil {
            self.processData(incomingUdpConnection)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: In simulator it works, but no on real devices. Implementing this additional check will  cause it to fail in both environments.

Comment: I tested this code successfully on the simulator and on my phone. Make sue you aren't creating another listener somewhere else in your code.

Comment: On the real device, please do exactly the following to reproduce the problem (as it would happen in real life also)
1. start app
2. receive UDP packages (without this step it will not fail)
3. stop
4. Now you will not be able to restart listening again.

Comment: I can reproduce it on all my Macs and iOS devices. All latest Xcode/iOS. But only after the iOS device received UDP packages successfully.

Comment: Ok. I was able to reproduce it.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this , just one additional question, if I assume to receive 5 messages per second, this will end up in 18000 `NWConnection`s keeping alive after one hour. Would it make sense to close each previous `NWConnection` before calling `processData`? like so: `self.connections.first?.cancel(); self.connections.removeAll(where: {incomingUdpConnection === $0})`?

Comment: It depends on how your clients are sending data. Your test script was establishing a new connection each second.  Generally you would want a client to reuse the same source port so that it is just seen as additional data in the same connection. When using UDP you really need some sort of framing in your data so that you can work out when the client is done and reassemble fragmented data. TCP does this for you and may be a better choice for long lived connections.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes absolutely sense, I was not aware that the source port indicates a new _connection_. But I tried it with `echo "1234" | nc -cu -w 0 192.168.2.106 55555 -p 55000` and you are of course right it re-uses the same NWConnection when the source port does not change! However I'm happy to have now very robust code that can deal with both situations stable! Thanks again! (BTW: I assume the real hardware device that sends UDP related to the specs will also reuse the same source port, I just had it not available for my tests, so I simulated it with netcat)