# NWConnection WebSocket Error: nw_ws_validate_client_request - client request doesn't match expected value

Tags: ios, swift, networking, websocket

When I send a message without a `WebSocket` I can successfully send and receive it:

```
var browser: NWBrowser?
init() {

    let parameters = NWParameters()
    parameters.includePeerToPeer = true
    parameters.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
        
    browser = NWBrowser(for: .bonjour(type: "_myApp_.tcp", domain: "local"), using: parameters)
    // start browser
}

var listener: NWListener?
init() {

    let parameters = NWParameters()
    parameters.includePeerToPeer = true
    parameters.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
        
    listener = try? NWListener(using: params)
    listener?.service = NWListener.Service(name: "MyName", type: "_myApp_.tcp")
    // start listener
}
```

But when I do use a WebSocket, `NWConnection` returns a `.failed` case and the debugger prints:

> nw_ws_validate_client_request [C4:1] client request doesn't match
> expected value
>
> POSIXErrorCode: Software caused
> connection abort
>
> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Network.NWError error 0.)

**Where am I going wrong with the WebSocket code?**

```
var browser: NWBrowser?
init() {

    let tcpOptions = NWProtocolTCP.Options()
    tcpOptions.enableKeepalive = true
    tcpOptions.keepaliveIdle = 2
    let parameters = NWParameters(tls: nil, tcp: tcpOptions)
    parameters.includePeerToPeer = true
    parameters.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
    
    let webSocketOptions = NWProtocolWebSocket.Options()
    webSocketOptions.autoReplyPing = true
    parameters.defaultProtocolStack.applicationProtocols.insert(webSocketOptions, at: 0)
        
    browser = NWBrowser(for: .bonjour(type: "_myApp_.tcp", domain: "local"), using: parameters)
    // start browser
}

var listener: NWListener?
init() {

    let tcpOptions = NWProtocolTCP.Options()
    tcpOptions.enableKeepalive = true
    tcpOptions.keepaliveIdle = 2
    let parameters = NWParameters(tls: nil, tcp: tcpOptions)
    parameters.includePeerToPeer = true
    parameters.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
    
    let webSocketOptions = NWProtocolWebSocket.Options()
    webSocketOptions.autoReplyPing = true
    parameters.defaultProtocolStack.applicationProtocols.insert(webSocketOptions, at: 0)
        
    listener = try? NWListener(using: parameters)
    listener?.service = NWListener.Service(name: "MyName", type: "_myApp_.tcp")
    // start listener
}
```

NWConnection:

```
connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (nwConnectionState) in

    case .failed(let error):
         print(error.debugDescription)
         print(error.localizedDescription)
         connection.cancel()
}
```

Message:

```
let data = "hello".data(using: .utf8)
let message = NWProtocolWebSocket.Metadata(opcode: .text)
let context = NWConnection.ContentContext(identifier: "send", metadata: [message])
connection.send(content: data, contentContext: context, isComplete: true, completion: .contentProcessed({ (error) in
    if let error = error { return }
        
    print("Successfully Sent: \(data.count) bytes")
}))
```

Comment: No WebSocket configuration stuff belongs into the browser, the browser is always using mDNS. I don't see where in your code you are connecting to the listener. WebSocket is a TCP protocol, it needs a client side connection after discovery.

Comment: It would’ve been a lot of code to add. Here is an answer that I posted where I connect the Listener to a NWConnection. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264070/4833705. The code in that answer doesn’t use a web socket though.